# Excel - How to update picture of table based on changes

Tags: excel, image

I have a table "A" that allows user input and the changes the user makes will affect table "B" in an other sheet. I'm looking for a way to put a picture of that table B next to table A. I cannot put table B directly next to the table A as it has hidden rows.

I want to create a macro that converts table B into a picture and posts it next to the table A. Once the user makes a change, the old picture will be deleted and an updated version will be posted. Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance!

This is my current code:

```
Call Sheet1.Range("A1:E12").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)
Sheet2.Shapes.AddChart
Sheet2.Activate
Sheet2.Shapes.Item(1).Select
Set objChart = ActiveChart
objChart.Paste
```

When I run it I get the error "Run-time error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set" but an chart does appear.

Answer (score 0):

Why a picture? If so, every time changes are made, with vba, print the area of the table to a .pdf or .xps and then paste it next to your table in sheet one.

Else just make references to the first sheets values so when entered the second one changes aswell? i.e. "=Sheet1!C6"

Might have missunderstood something please let me know.

Comment: I need to use a picture because its next to a table that has hidden rows, so if I were to paste just a table next to it, it would hide the second table's rows. Im having trouble getting my vba working to convert a range to a picture. Any ideas what the code would look like?

Comment: Tbh, I think you could just record the macro of you marking the table in the second sheet, save it as a .pdf and then paste it next to your existing table, it should overwrite the filename each time, if not please get back to me or maybe part of the macro code will at least get you started.